# override the default positioning of the arrow placed on MUI Tooltip

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to override the default positioning of the "small" arrow placed on MUI Tooltip. What I have tried so far is below but no success. I want to simply move it to the left of the tooltip.

```js
import * as React from "react";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import Tooltip from "@mui/material/Tooltip";

export default function PositionedTooltips() {
  return (
    <Tooltip
      title="Title here"
      placement="bottom-start"
      arrow
      sx={{
        "& .MuiTooltip-arrow": {
          left: "10px !important",
          transform: "none !important"
        }
      }}
      open={true}
    >
      <Button>Testing text that is a complete test</Button>
    </Tooltip>
  );
}
```

Comment: And what doesn't work? Seems like the box is at the bottom as you state in your code.

Comment: A proper [mre] of your issue belongs directly into your question, please do not just send us to external platforms to see relevant code.

Comment: @0stone0 the issue is with the placement of the small "arrow", not the tooltip itself. I am trying to move it to the left so it should be placed at the very top left.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to override the default styling of the arrow on Tooltip. For some reason the sx prop was not working but targeting at the MuiTooltip-arrow class directly in CSS worked perfectly.